# Can the genetic codex from Man of Steel still be used in the future?

Tags: dc, superman, dc-extended-universe, man-of-steel

Or did the end of the movie mean that all Kryptonians were completely extinct?

I was a bit confused by the end because it seemed to suggest that all kryptonians were completely extinct. But Jor-El couldn't have known and did not plan on having Zod follow his son to earth, especially with one of those birthing chambers in tow. So he must have assumed that there was another way..

Is it possible that Superman can still use the codex?